# change .resx file runtime causes session to expire

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx

I have created page to change the resource file dynamically by the web site admin. but now when user changes the value in resx file, it saves correctly but it causes the session to expire. How can i overcome this? Does anyone has idea about it, i tried to search but only to find that when we change .resx file it again compiles the website and causes app pool restarts.

Project is website and its in 4.0

Comment: you are using Inproc session mode, right?

Comment: now you should use StateServer . please go through this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971309/session-timeout-on-server-side-in-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: @Ashwini I dont want to change the session mode. Is there any setting i can use it to avoid this recompilation using inProc mode only?

Comment: unfortunately no. if you are losing session due to Application Pool restarts or resets. you have to switch to either StateServer or SqlServer.

Comment: Is there way i can prevent the app pool to restarts?

Comment: No you can not. in some scenario as it is mentioned in given link, Application Pool restarts and we can't stop it.

Comment: ok.. Lastly i am ended up using State server session mode... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the resx file, the worker process is recycled.  If you are using in-process session state, the sessions are lost.  Possible work-arounds: use out-of-process session storage, or store your resources outside of the virtual directory (and manage updating them yourself).

Ref: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/02.aspx