# Chrome assuming octet-stream to .png image

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps, mime-types

I have an application with **Google Maps API V3** and **ASP.Net** that uses [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pt-br#OverlayView) to set an custom icon on the map.

The image of that icon is set on `onAdd` event by setting the background CSS property with JavaScript. This image is **.png**.

This icon position is frequently changed by updates($.ajax) and, on that point, the image is downloaded again from the server. This causes a little blink - icon image disappear when another is downloading. It should change it's position without blinking.

The question is **"why browser doesn't caches the image?"**. The Chrome's Developer Tool shows that these images are coming with MIME Type of `"application/octet-stream"`. And on console I see this warning:

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://localhost:81/Common/Images/Synoptic/bus_b.png"

There's already a question about this on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235649/mime-type-warning-in-chrome-for-png-images) but it doens't helped me. I think my problem is more specific.

Comment: 1) your server does not understand png or 2) your server WANTS you to download the images instead of showing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a solution for this. I used a `.ashx` file header and controlled the cache there. This is the result:

```
path = context.Request.MapPath(path + context.Request.QueryString["name"]);

if (File.Exists(path))
{
    imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);

    context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(dt.ToFileTime()));
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageBytes);  
}
else 
{
    throw new SystemException("Image doesn't exists. '" + path + "'");
}
```

So the use is:

```
frmImageCaching.ashx?name=bus_b.png
```